# Regular Expression with wordpress shortcodes attributes

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, shortcode

We have following shortcodes,

```
[show_portfolio get="yachts" for="sale" in="europe" sort="length_overall" by="asc" page="1" perpage="18" theme="active-71" ref="http://replaceme.com" debug="true" engine="engine.com"]

[get_portfolio get="yachts" for="sale" in="europe" sort="length_overall" by="asc" page="1" perpage="18" theme="active-71" ref="http://replaceme.com" debug="true" engine="engine.com"]
```

We would like to replace http://replaceme.com with http://targetadress.com

Replacing with following regex is not good idea because of it catches a href tags as well
`ref="[^"\r\n]*"`

https://regex101.com/r/q1uumb/1/

I was wondering if someone help me to replace http://replaceme.com with http://targetadress.com inside **(show|get)_portfolio** tags

I could not find a way to run following regex `\[(show|get)_portfolio ref="(.+)"]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: This needs some clarification: Are these shortcodes already in your content? Is the `ref` value the same for all of them? Where are you trying to run the regex?

Comment: @disinfor Shortcodes already in content. ref value is always different. However attribute name (ref) is always same

Comment: Is this your shortcode? Or from a theme/plugin? Is the new `targetadress.com` always the same? Or is it if `replaceme.com` is a particular value, then the `targetadress.com` will be a particular value?

Comment: Yes this is our shortcode. It is not a theme/plugin. targetadress.com is always different also. It should be variable

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/370139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```sh
$repl = preg_replace(
   '\[(?:show|get)_portfolio\s+[^]]* ref="\Khttp://replaceme\.com"',
   'http://targetadress.com"',
   $str);
```

If you want to match any URL in the `ref=` then use:

```sh
$repl = preg_replace(
   '\[(?:show|get)_portfolio\s+[^]]*\s+ref="\K[^"]+"',
   'http://targetadress.com"',
   $str);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q1uumb/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\[`: Match a `[`
- `(?:show|get)_portfolio`: Match `get_portfolio` or `show_portfolio`
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `[^]]*\s+ref="`: Match 0 or more non-`]` characters followed by 1+ whitespace followed by `ref=`
- `\K`: Reset match info
- `http://replaceme\.com"`:L Match `http://replaceme\.com"`

Comment: You saved my day. I was wondering if you correct RexEx Demo address for future reference.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to add finish "]" as well?

Comment: That would be unnecessary and inefficient since all we need is `ref="..."` inside the short-code. We are using `[^]]*` to make sure `ref=` comes before closing `]`

Comment: @anumhava I just did it.

Comment: @anumhava, Is it possible to regex http://replaceme.com instead of http://replaceme.com" without (")?

Comment: Yes try: `'\[(?:show|get)_portfolio\s+[^]]* ref="\Khttp://replaceme\.com(?=")'`

Comment: Would you please do it for '\[(?:show|get)_portfolio\s+[^]]*\s+ref="\K[^"]+"' also?

Comment: I think it will be \[(?:show|get)_portfolio\s+[^]]*\s+ref="\K[^"]+(?=")

Comment: yes that's right or just: `\[(?:show|get)_portfolio\s+[^]]*\s+ref="\K[^"]+`